# How to create and use PayPal sandbox accounts?

Tags: c#, paypal

I am absolutely novice to PayPal api, I need to integrate PayPal in an MVC 4 Store. I have been reading a lot of tutorials on-line and it seems that you need to create two dummy account (buyer and seller) on PayPal sandbox site. I think PayPal have done a major update to their developer site lately and I cannot understand one bit of where should I create these accounts and will they be free or not? Is there any updated resource still valid with the new PayPal updated site out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the sandbox account , Just login to developer.paypal.com with your PayPal credentials . Once you logged move to Dashboard . Follow the below screen shot :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Eshan, Plus 1 for the screen shots!