# Website Paypal Connection with Php

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Im trying to connect my website with paypal and i have the index page where i am getting the order price,
the order name and then i refer them to the process.php using get for processing.Howevever,on running the process.php file i am getting this error

```
Error : Security header is not valid
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2014%2d10%2d07T17%3a22%3a00Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 37359d983e7a
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 109%2e0
    [BUILD] => 13243702
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Security%20error
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Security%20header%20is%20not%20valid
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

How can i solve this error.Please Assist

Comment: Is this error being returned from the PayPal API?  Presumably you've sent it an invalid security header.  That's what you'd need to correct.

Comment: Hi David,im new to paypal connection and i'm un aware about security headers how can i go about it,please asssist

Comment: PayPal offers some documentation on the subject: https://developer.paypal.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261766/paypal-gateway-has-rejected-request-security-header-is-not-valid-10002-secur/23265150#23265150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes in when :

1. You are using the wrong credentials ( make sure you have not copied any white spaces in apiusername. password and the signature .
2. You are using the wrong endpoints . Meaning you are using test credentials in live mode or vice versa .

Comment: Thanks Eshan it has worked, and how can i get the sandbox credentials

Comment: You can follow below link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041497/how-to-create-and-use-paypal-sandbox-accounts/26043735#26043735

Comment: Thanks Eshan i have created the account,please and how can i access the sandbox credentials

Comment: hae Eshan when i change the $paypalmode to sandbox it is still giving me the old error,which sandbox credentials can i use

Comment: You need to get the credentials by following the steps in my previous comment

Comment: Hae Eshan thanks for your concern.I have followed the earlier comment on how to create a sandbox account and i followed it to the later.However,i'm confused where to get those sandbox credentials because i am using the live credentials which are economical to use to test your paypal transactions.Please if you could attach a screen shot i would be very happy.

Comment: Thanks Eshan i have prospered well,thanks in advance